# Karate-config.js file is not saved as JS file in eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, cucumber, karate, cucumber-junit

[image]

This is how it looks like inside file

[image]

I did this eclipse preference also :

[image]

Comment: note that screen shots are not useful, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Check in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations.  For *.js file type select any relevant script editor as default (For e.g JS Editor) in the Associated editors window and apply.

If *.js is not present under file types, add it and select JS Editor as default in Associated Editors pane.

Comment: Its not working even after added (.js) with Jscrip encoded and Java script editot as associated file type.

Comment: What's the version of eclipse and the file editor you have selected?

Comment: I just updating my eclipse to 2020 version and I dint have any Java Script Viewer in the options